# How to capture and propagate a wildcard type argument?

Tags: java, generics

I have a couple of classes having identical methods, except with respect to certain parameter types:

```
interface ICls<T> {
    void doSomething(String key, T value);
    Map<String, T> getSomething();
}

class ClsA implements ICls<Boolean> {
    @Override public void doSomething(String key, Boolean value) { }
    @Override public Map<String, Boolean> getSomething() { return Map.of(); }
}

class ClsB implements ICls<String> {
    @Override public void doSomething(String key, String value) {}
    @Override public Map<String, String> getSomething() { return Map.of(); }
}
```

Now I'm trying to have a main class that stores a mixed list of these class objects and for each of these instances, passes info between its two methods:

```
class Main {
    List<ICls<?>> list = List.of(
        new ClsA(),
        new ClsB()
    );
    void run() {
        list.forEach(cls -> {
            Map<String, ?> data = cls.getSomething();
            data.keySet().forEach(key -> cls.doSomething(key, data.get(key)));
        });
    }
```

The `List<ICls<?>>` and `Map<String, ?>` statements are OK. However, the `map.get(key)` throws an IDE error:

```
'doSomething(<String, capture<?>>) in '...ICls' cannot be applied to 'String, capture<?>'
```

Hovering the mouse cursor over the offending statement shows:

```
Required type: capture of ?
Provided: capture of ?
```

Assuming that I can't/don't want to change the generic type `T` to `Object`, and don't want to change the architecture either, what can I do to make the code here compile?

I've tried changing the signature of `doSomething` so that it accepts the entire `Map<String, T>` and call it like so, with no luck either:

```
cls.doSomething(cls.getSomething());
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm curious whether we *can* convince Java that the types are okay here. What you're describing certainly makes logical and mathematical sense, but I'm not sure if Java's type system is smart enough for it. This may be a case of "cast through `Object` and bypass the type checker", but I'll defer to someone more in tune with Java's intricacies to say for certain.

Comment: @azurefrog Typo! My bad. Just corrected and checked the entire code in IDE. :)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Thank you! I would hate to do that. :( Otherwise I'd rather just have a `Map<String, Object>` in the first place. Would make code simpler, although I'd have to convert the `Object` to an appropriate type inside each class every time. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This compiles for me:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Comparison {
    interface ICls<T> {
        void doSomething(String key, T value);
        Map<String, T> getSomething();
    }
    static class ClsA implements ICls<Boolean> {
        public void doSomething(String key, Boolean value) {}
        public Map<String, Boolean> getSomething() { return null; }
    }

    static class ClsB implements ICls<String> {
        public void doSomething(String key, String value) {}
        public Map<String, String> getSomething() { return null; }
    }

    static class Main {

        List<ICls<?>> list = List.of(
                new ClsA(),
                new ClsB()
        );
        void run() {
            list.forEach(cls -> {
                doIt(cls);
            });
        }
        
        <T> void doIt(ICls<T> cls) {
            Map<String, T> data = cls.getSomething();
            data.keySet().forEach(key -> cls.doSomething(key, data.get(key)));
        }
    }
}
```

It makes clear the relationship between the map and the cls.

In the original context, because the type of the List is ICls<?> we can't get that relationship, but once we get a single ICls we can introduce a type variable `T` which allows us to express the relationship between `getSomething` and `doSomething`.

Comment: Wowww!!! Yes it indeed compiles just fine! Btw I removed the `static` modifiers and it still compiles fine. Can you elaborate why your code works and mine doesn't?

Comment: I think `?` can't resolve the type there, that's why you need to work with T, helping compiler a little more to understand the type.  And for that, you have to extract that part to another method.

Comment: I just need the statics because I'm wrapping everything in an outer class.